# efficient way to initialize a large vector-of in clojure

Tags: performance, clojure

Vector-of in clojure is a performant way to do operations because the internal values are unboxed. I can create an array like this:

```
(time (count (apply vector-of :double (repeat 100000 0))));
; "Elapsed time: 1703.597 msecs"
```

But it is very slow. Is there a faster way (there must be)? Note: preallocation of a vector is important for assoc since assoc will generate an out-of-bounds error if it trys to set an element beyond the length of a vector.

**Edit:**

This has a solution for now (see answer). Leon Grapenthin posted this as a bug on github [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1695).

Comment: Apparently the variadic overload of `vector-of` is not optimized for large input. I have created an issue about it here http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1695

Comment: FYI its now fixed on master https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/bcb8e9a7aa0b0588b4872384256d86bf53d12f15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run OP's code, to get base time on my machine. (Mac Pro 2009 2.66 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 48 GB RAM. Clojure 1.6.0. Java 1.8.0_40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM.)

```
user> (time (count (apply vector-of :double (repeat 100000 0))))
"Elapsed time: 992.688709 msecs"
100000
```

Try `(repeat 100000 0.0)` to eliminate long to double conversion. Not much change.

```
user> (time (count (apply vector-of :double (repeat 100000 0.0))))
"Elapsed time: 965.876047 msecs"
100000
```

Create the vector, then add the elements, much faster:

```
user> (time (count (into (vector-of :double) (repeat 100000 0.0))))
"Elapsed time: 52.856371 msecs"
100000
```

Somewhat faster, don't build a lazy sequence:

```
(defn n-conj [n coll elem]
  (if (zero? n)
    coll
    (recur (dec n) (conj coll elem) elem)))

(time (count (n-conj 100000 (vector-of :double) 0.0)))
"Elapsed time: 37.86183 msecs"
100000
```

Comment: I'm surprised something like `n-conj` doesn't exist already, but I could not find it.

Comment: Note: I ran the timing on Clojure 1.7 Alpha 6, and the `(into ...` version was quite a bit faster, about 27 milliseconds, with `n-conj` at 30 milliseconds. So `n-conj` faster than 1.6, but slower the the 1.7's `into`. `(apply ...` was still slow, at 860 milliseconds.